# IAX registration procedure in C++

Tags: c++, voip

I need to verify an IAX account in my C++ client and run third-party softphone if account's credentials are valid (or close an application if not).

So, the client's socket connects to Asterisk host via UDP (port 4569) and... What is the algorithm? The [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5456#page-12) does not contains any examples and I can't understand the structure of registration procedure (headers, data order etc.)

**Could somebody explain me the order and the structure of messages to perform IAX user authentication?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the document you have pointed, you can see the procedure of registration in chapter 6.1

```
                     ________________
                    |                |
                    |  Unregistered  |<--------------------------\
                    |________________|                           |
                            |                                    |
              /Init         |                                    |
              ------------  |                                    |
              snd REGREQ    |    +--------+                      |
                            |    |        | rec REGAUTH          |
                     _______V____V___     | -----------          |
                    |                |    | snd REGREQ           |
                    |   Reg Sent     +----+                      |
                    |________________+----------+                |
                            |    ^              | rec REGAUTH    |
               rec REGACK   |    |              | /No Credentials|
              ------------  |    | REG timeout  | -------------- |
               snd ack      |    | -------      | snd ack        |
                            |    | REGREQ     __V___             |
                     _______V____|___        |      |            |
                    |                |       |  No  |            |
                    |   Registered   |       | Auth |            |
                    |________________|       |______|            |
                            |                   ^                |
                            |                   | rec REGAUTH    |
                            | release           | /No Credentials|
                            | -------           | -------------- |
              +-------+     | snd REGREL        | snd ack        |
 rec REGAUTH  |       |     |                   |                |
 -----------  |      _V_____V________           |                |
 snd REGREL   |     |                |----------+                |
              +-----+   Releasing    |---------------------------+
                    |________________|      rec ACK
                                            -------
                                               x

                 __________
rec  REGREJ     |          |
----------   *->| Rejected |
snd   ack       |__________|
```

Messages REGAUTH, REGREQ, etc. are specified in paragraphs 6.1.2 to 6.1.5 as messasges containing **Information elements**.

Information elements are included in full frames that are specified in paragraph 8.1.1

```
                    1                   2                   3 
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|F|     Source Call Number      |R|   Destination Call Number   |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                            time-stamp                         |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|    OSeqno     |    ISeqno     |   Frame Type  |C|  Subclass   |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                                                               |
:                             Data                              :
|                                                               |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

                Figure 5: Full Frame Binary Format
```

Frame type for REGREQ, etc. is IAX (8.2.6) and the classes of IAX frames, including registration messages are in 8.4

Information elements for registration are enumerated in 6.1.x and described in 8.6.x

Anyway, you can use wireshark if you want to see a dialog message to message

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying and for the advice about wireshark. I tried to catch messages with wireshark but it has no success with VPN connection to real Asterisk - messages was encrypted. Everything became clear when I installed local server to virtual machine